# Connection object with multiple threads using Dependency injection

Tags: multithreading, dependency-injection, unit-of-work

I have been trying to add parallel foreach in existing application and faced an odd issue

Application Architecture

1. Controller resolve BO layer
2. BO Layer resolve Service Layer
3. Service Layer resolve UOW and Repository Layer
4. UOW layer resolve DB Connection

**BO Layer**

```
private IUserService _userService; 
public BOUser(IUserService userService) => _userService=userService; 

public void AddUser(User user) => _userService.addUser(user);
```

**Service Layer**

```
private IUnitofWork _uow;
private IUserRepository _userRepo;
UserService(IUOW _uow, IUserRepository _userRepo)
{
    uow = _uow;
    _userRepo.uow = _uow;
}

public void AddUser (User user) {
    _uow.BeginTransaction();
    _userRepo.Add(user);
    _uow.CommitTransaction();
}
```

**Repo Layer**

```
public IUnitOfWork UnitOfWork { get; set; }
public void Add(user){
    UnitOfWork.Connection.Insert<UserContact>(userContact, UnitOfWork.Transaction);
}
```

**Unit of Work**

```
public UnitOfWork(IDbConnection connection)
{
    Connection = connection; // responsible for creating new connection
}
```

This works fine as of today but as i tried to add multiple user using parallel.foreach in BO layer i got one failed and one success

Reason behind is service layer is initiated when BO layer initiated and UOW.connection remains to be 1 for whole process
when i tried multiple threads because Connection was one object that was shared between multiple threads
it failed because one thread completed the work and closed Connection object

i have solution in mind by removing UOW from Constructor and by using service location pattern that would be

```
IUserSrevice userService = new UserService();
```

that will create multiple connection object based on threads.

its not rite way of doing it. Any expert opinion will help

Comment: Please show the code with the parallel foreach.

Answer (score 0):

`Connection` is not a thread safe object because the idea is to create a pool of connection objects and have each thread borrow a connection from the pool, do its work and return it to the pool once done.

Thus no more than one thread can access a connection object at a time.

You should inject the connection pool and not the individual connection objects.

Comment: inject Connection Pool , can you bit elaborate

Comment: @Salman how you do it may vary with language and frameworks. But the generic idea is you maintain a pool object that manages all connections. You create one instance of the pool and hand it over to all other objects that connect to the DB. The individual classes then borrow a connection from the pool and return it after the DB operation. Please study the connection pooling in the language and framework you're using

Comment: This is handled by frameworks like .NET have 100 connection in pool by default . my Question was bit different i was talking about single connection thats get closed and open in different database calls .